Where do I report a bug in the xubuntu.org website?
If the download page on Xubuntu's website https://xubuntu.org/download/ , I can see this text:

If you absolutely must use a CD to install your system, and you’re able to download updates while doing an install, we recommend using the Minimal CD, which is tiny and easily fits on a CD. It uses the text-based alternate installer, which is better for older hardware.

This is confusing. The Xubuntu mimimal .iso is 2.7GB big, and it does not fit on a CD, nor does it use a text-based installer. Where can I report this bug in the web page?

In the footer of the Xubuntu.org website, there is a "contact us" link. In this page, you can find the answer to your question:

Found an error on the website content?
Contact us xubuntu-devel@lists.ubuntu.com and we’ll look to fix the errors and improve the website!

You can send an email to the public mailing list xubuntu-devel@lists.ubuntu.com to report issues with the website.
